# How to import this file generated by mysql phpmyadmin export back into the table?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I did an sql export of a mysql table in phpmyadmin and was given a textfile which looks like this:

```
"property";"367158";"4012";"5";"sold";"2013-02-06 05:40:27"
"property";"367159";"4013";"5";"sold";"2013-02-06 09:51:52"
```

Notice the lack of semi-colon at the end of the row.

I have hundreds of these rows like above. How do I easily import these data entries back into the table?

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar long ago, try something like this in mysql command line:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/workbench/test-file.csv' INTO TABLE properties
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

If does not work you can modify according to you needs such as end of line, file name, file path, etc.

For more info have a look:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-data.html

Comment: This only works if the OP has command line access and can run the MySQL command line.

Answer (score 0):

What you have is a delimited file.  I believe that this format is supported by phpmyadmin import.  Choose delimited format, set the delimiter to ';' and do the import.

Answer (score 0):

in phpmyadmin go to import tab and there you will see options like fields separated by,etc mark them according to the file and click ok